# Next Previous Button via SelectBox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I want to do the following:

I have a Select Box when I click a page number in the process of changing product does well, what I want to do now is to click on a the Select Box icon automatically advance to the next value (page).

This is my Select Box, and work's fine:

[image]

```
     <td colspan="3">page
        <select id="numPage">
            @if (ViewBag.pages == 0)
            {
                <option value="0" selected>0</option>
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= ViewBag.pages; i++)
                {
                    if (ViewBag.Nowpage == i)
                    {
                <option id="Now" value="@(i)" selected>@(i)</option>   
                    }
                    else
                    {
                <option id="Next" value="@(i)">@(i)</option>   
                    }
                }
            }
        </select>
    de @(ViewBag.pages)</td>
```

these are my buttons for first previous next or last pages:

[image]

```
<div>
  <div id="startPage"><i class="fa fa-step-backward"></i></div>
  <div id="previousPage"><i class="fa fa-backward"></i></div>
  <div id="nextPage"><i class="fa fa-forward"></i></div>
  <div id="lastPage"><i class="fa fa-step-forward"></i></div>
</div>
```

here I am on page 4 but I want to move to page 4 when clicking on the icon to advance:

[image]

when clicking the last page icon to advance to the last page in Select Box:

[image]

I'm programming with JQUERY and MVC 4 any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this works:

```
$("#nextPage").on("click", function(){
    changeIndex(true);
});

$("#previousPage").on("click", function(){
    changeIndex(false);
});

function changeIndex(val)
{
    var i = $("#numPage").prop("selectedIndex");
    $("#numPage").prop("selectedIndex", i + (val ? 1:-1));
    $("#numPage").trigger("change");
}

$("#numPage").on("change", function(){
    console.log("I got triggered");
});
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/4c7LV/

Make sure to check that the index is not outside the bounds on your select, by comparing it against how many items it has.